# Command line switches, flags, options

Tags: terminology

What is the difference between switches, flags and options when you want to specify something on the command line? Are they all synonyms?

Are there any reasons why some terminals require:

```
-op1 --option2
```

and others:

```
/option1 /option2
```

and when processing data, some require:

```
--data file.txt
```

and others:

```
/data=file.txt
```

or even:

```
/c:data=file.txt
```

?

Comment: It's completely arbitrary. Different conventions are used in different systems.

Comment: I don't think this is a question about computer *science*; it seems more like a question about the syntax of shell commands on a particular platform.